# Ajax request remove class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two cards. One card with an input where a user enters a postcode and another card which has two radio buttons for the user to select if they are a student. This card is hidden at first.
I have an Ajax request that checks if the postcode exits. If the postcode does exist that card turns green (card--success) and then the user can select if they are a student in the other card which is unhidden when they have entered an existing postcode.
If the postcode does not exist the card turns red (card--danger) and the other student card remains hidden. 
All of this is working fine.

I now need to remove the red colour (card--danger) after the user enters an invalid postcode by accident then needs to re-enter the postcode correctly. Because at the moment if the user re-enters another postcode after entering an invalid postcode the card is still red (card--danger) even if they re-enter a valid postcode.

What would the best way be to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#student-select').addClass('hidden');
    $('.submit-postcode').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var value = $('#inputPostcode').val();

        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {postcode: value},
            url: '/postcode'
        }).done(function(data) {
           $('#postcode-card').addClass('card--success');
           $('#student-select').removeClass('hidden');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            $('#postcode-card').addClass('card--danger');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes thank you I really appreciate it, all of your answers work :)

Comment: What would the best way be to add an error message when it's an invalid postcode, along side the card--danger? I have tried adding an error alert which works but not a great user experience. It would be better to display an error message under the input field.

Comment: You can add a hidden div after your input and if there is an error you can just show it. Anyway i would suggest checking other answers in stackoverflow regarding that or there isn't any ask a new question

Comment: That's great, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove class when you get a success response

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#student-select').addClass('hidden');
    $('.submit-postcode').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var value = $('#inputPostcode').val();

        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {postcode: value},
            url: '/postcode'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#postcode-card').removeClass('card--danger');
           $('#postcode-card').addClass('card--success');
           $('#student-select').removeClass('hidden');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            $('#postcode-card').addClass('card--danger');
        })
    });
});
```

Or if you want to change it before the request is sent for validation you can remove class when user changes the input

```
$('#inputPostcode').on('change', function() {
    $('#postcode-card').removeClass('card--danger');
});
```

or when user focuses in the input

```
$('#inputPostcode').on('focus', function() {
    $('#postcode-card').removeClass('card--danger');
});
```

But I believe that it would be better to remove it after you verify it in the backed

Answer (score 0):

put this inside your fail callback:

```
$('#inputPostcode').on('change', function() {
    $('#postcode-card').removeClass('card--danger');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the both classes from postcode-card before sending the ajax request.

```
 $('#postcode-card').removeClass("card--success card--danger");
```